# lodash debounce cancel() not stopping the debounce execution

Tags: angular, typescript, lodash, debouncing, angular-event-emitter

I have written an angular application in which im making http calls on each `modelChange` event. I have used lodash `_.debounce()`. The issue is im not able to cancel these calls after the first successful execution of debounce.

```
  modelChangeEvent(item):void {
   const _this = this;
   let debounceObj = _.debounce(function(){
     _this.makeHttpCall(item);
     debounceObj.cancel();
    },600);
  debounceObj();
  }
```

https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#debounce

Comment: Why don't you use rxjs? It comes with Angular and already has dozens of similar functionalities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implemented using Rxjs `debounceTime()` and `distinctUntilChanged()`

```
detectInput:any = new Subject();

ngOnInit(){
  this.detectInput.pipe(debounceTime(400),distinctUntilChanged()).subscribe(value=>{
    this.makeHttpCall(value)
  })
}

modelChangeEvent(item):void {
 this.detectInput.next(item);
}
```